# Typescript, combine object types of tuple elements

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to take a tuple of different objects, and get a type of all of these objects combined? For example if i have a tuple like this:

```
const t = tuple({current: 1}, {old: 2}, {new: 3}); //this should be interpreted as [{current: number;}, {old: number;}, {new: number;}]
```

and then i combine those objects into a single one:

```
let newob = {};
for(let ob of t) {
  Object.assign(newob, ob);
}
```

can I somehow make typescript treat this new object as a

```
typeof t[0] & typeof t[1] & typeof t[2]
```

which in this case would be

```
{current: number; old: number; new: number;}
```

without manually typing that all?

I'd like it to work with any tuple and any objects inside tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the parameters in a tuple type using a generic type parameter with a constraint of `any[]` for a rest parameter. You can the use `UnionToIntersection` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to merge all tuple item types into a single intersection type

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...t: T) {
  let newob = {} ;
  for (let ob of t) {
    Object.assign(newob, ob);
  }
  return newob as UnionToIntersection<T[number]>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oBYAKCigAoYoIAPHOAE3xQAhnBBQA-OwDWALlgBKWlQBuSBPyjy4EFXgVdeEAULZs5UBHABmeKBiWr1-A1IxaoOvbmbWArnAkZFDAfmAANhDkqIZ8giJiANoAulRsAHSZwPKoBgDezKyRwJ4QAO5IAEZ0UHkAvlAA3IVQ1ki47MVQVd3WIfktrADylQBWxMDpwvj4CADmcGw6FZUANN2VCs0sUHUtuBChuHClKyJC8GToWDgEE2TRiXB+ALaVeKnbe0zMRCj4JRK9FCEQgbDyUCIflwB2w8gAjLt1hCkOF+PIAExI2qneQAZl2W2YAHpiSF5AUmKTWDSoTDjNlPK93rhttSGgAyWoksk07po7TMvBssmc7lU3k05aCt7Cnm7IA)

Comment: Thanks, this does work. However I noticed a strange behavior, it isn't really a big problem, but if you try to put into tuple two class instance objects, and both of them have a private method of the same name, the whole thing return type of 'never'. Doesn't happen if methods are public or protected. [Here's demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nh1q1d?file=index.ts)

Comment: There is a `No overload matches this call` error.

Comment: @LinDu fixed the build error. Some type compatibility changed since posted this 4 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet types better your arguments and return types:

```
type Cast<From, To> = From extends To ? From : never;
type FoldIntoIntersection<T extends readonly {}[], Acc extends {} = {}> = T extends readonly [infer H, ...infer HS] 
    ? FoldIntoIntersection<Cast<HS, readonly {}[]>, Acc & H> 
    : Acc;

function tuple<const T extends readonly {}[]>(...t: T) {
  let newob: FoldIntoIntersection<T> = {} as any;
  for (let ob of t) {
    Object.assign(newob, ob);
  }
  return newob;
}
```

Comment: A good answer, I'd still choose `UnionToIntersection`. The behavior is built into the compiler and is probably faster than a recursive conditional type (even a tail recursive one)